# BREAK in AWK doesn't work

Tags: loops, awk, break

I have:

```
AGT GTT TTA CAT TTT GTA TTT TTT TTC TAA ATT CTG AGT GTA GTC TTC CCT
```

My desired output is:

```
AGT GTT TTA CAT TTT
```

My code:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf $i" "; if ($i~/TTT/) {break}}}'
```

However, it seems that break doesn't work cause it prints:

```
AGT GTT TTA CAT TTT GTA TTT TTT TTC TAA ATT CTG AGT GTA GTC TTC CCT
```

Comment: What if you change `break` for `exit`? In both cases it works to me.

Comment: Just added it as an answer so you can accept it + new people entering the question can have clear what was the issue instead of reading from comments.

Comment: `break` stops a looping process within `awk`.  `exit` stops all that `awk` does and exits `awk`

Comment: Not quite. `break` takes you out of the current context whether that's a loop or a switch statement (gawk) and `exit` takes you to the END section unless you're already in the `END` section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated on the comments, changing `break` for `exit` can make it:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf $i" "; if ($i~/TTT/) exit}}' file
```

---

Note you can delete the brackets around an action if there is only one:

```
if () {command}  <== equivalent ==>   if () command
```

but

```
if () {command1; command2} <== NOT equivalent ==>  if () command1; command2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
AGT GTT TTA CAT TTT GTA TTT TTT TTC TAA ATT CTG AGT GTA GTC TTC CCT
$ awk '{sub(/TTT.*/,"TTT")}1' file
AGT GTT TTA CAT TTT
```